# custom progress bar: can't locate it at the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm working on implementing my own progress bar, the problem is that it doesn't fill the screen and the dots are really small. What I'm trying to do is something like this: [image]

but what I got was this : [image]

What should I do to make my progress bar fill the screen horizontally when it's in portrait orientation ? and fill it vertically when it is in a landscape orientation? Also I want to have some space between the circles how can I do that?

This is my cutomprogressbar.xml code:

**EDITED**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/des"
            android:src="@drawable/gray"
            android:tag="1" />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgTwo" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="2"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgThree" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="3"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgFour" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="4"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgFive" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="5"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgSix" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="6"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgSeven" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="7"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgEight" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="8"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgNine" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"


           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="9"
            />
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/imgTen" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"

           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:contentDescription="@string/des"
           android:src="@drawable/gray"
           android:tag="10"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will use Linear layout in this case. Set `android:orientation="Horizontal"` in portrait resource file and "Vertical" in landscape resource file (you need two files one in /res/layout and second in /res/layout-land)

**EDIT**
try making following changes:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        <Img1
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img2
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
       <Img3
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img4
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img5
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img6
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img7
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img8
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img9
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
        <Img10
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />
/>
```

Share your results.

Comment: It didn't align to the center of the screen.

Comment: `<LinearLayout 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />`

Comment: didn't work too, the progress bar is at the top of the screen not center

Comment: sorry my bad `android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" ' and for space between circles, `android:padding=4dp` in each ImageView

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that it reflect all the changes I have to made?